# How to delete a file on exceptions for multiple reasons

Tags: java, file-io, transactions

I have a servlet which reads multipart data and saves a file to some temporary location. Then calls an ejb stateless service, one of whose method will take the file path as a string argument.

In the service I check

1. The file type as zip/tar/Z file. If not a valid archive a throw a RuntimeException.
2. Then unzip/untar/unZ and check if there is a particular xml file. If the file doesn't exist in the archive a throw a RuntimeException
3. Then I use JAXB to unmarshal the xml. If the unmarshal fails due to any reason I throw a RuntimeException.
4. Then I save the unmarshalled object to the database.
5. Then I delete the file before returning success to the client.

How can I do this efficiently without having to call file.delete() from multiple places in the service?

Below is some raw code how I wrote it

```
... service() {

    extractDescriptor(filePath);
}

... extractDescriptor(String filePath) {
    String extension = filePath.substring(filePath.lastIndexOf(".") + 1).toLowerCase();
    switch(extension) {
        case "zip":
        unzipper.extractFromZip(filePath);
        break;
        case "tar":
        untar.extractFromTar(filePath);
        break;
        case "z":
        untar.extractFromZ(filePath);
        break;
        default:
        new File("filePath").delete();
        throw RuntimeException("invalid extention");
    }
}
```

In Unzipper

```
ZipEntry entry = zipFile.getEntry("descriptor.xml");
if(entry == null) {
    file.delete();
    throw new RuntimeException("descriptor xml not found");
}
```

The same is with Untar

I don't know much about transactions. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Why not enclose all 5 steps in a try catch and the execute delete on finally? Do the return success outside the try-catch-finally block.

Comment: Yeah I had that idea but I thought try and catch would make the code ugly and thought if there is any better way using transactions.

Answer (score 2):

Just wrap the body of `extractDescriptor()` in a `try/finally`, with `new file(filePath).delete();` in the finally block.  Then the file will get deleted whether you exit normally (and are done using the file) or throw an exception.